# MySQL: aggregate changes for multiple objects from a temporary table

Tags: mysql, aggregate, temporary

I have a table like this, where every status change for every character is saved.

```
table characters_changes
+----+--------+---------+-------+----------------------+
| id |  rank  |   job   | money |      datetime        |
+----+--------+---------+-------+----------------------+
| 1  |   2    | tailor  |  25   | 2018-06-01 12:30:15  |
| 1  |   3    |  NULL   |   5   | 2018-06-02 10:50:19  |
| 1  |   2    |  NULL   |  -5   | 2018-06-03 18:44:35  |
| 1  |  NULL  | tinker  |  10   | 2018-06-04 04:10:12  |
| 1  |   3    |  NULL   | NULL  | 2018-06-05 17:31:00  |
|  2 |    1   |   spy   |   7   |  2018-06-01 12:30:15 |
|  2 |    2   |   NULL  |  NULL |  2018-06-02 10:50:19 |
|  2 |   NULL |  no job |   7   |  2018-06-03 17:31:00 |
| 3  |   3    | soldier |  12   | 2018-06-01 12:30:15  |
| 3  |   1    |  NULL   | -11   | 2018-06-02 10:50:19  |
+----+--------+---------+-------+----------------------+
```

`NULL` means that there was no change at corresponding attribute.
rank and job changes mean replace one with another,
while money change means adding and subtracting the sum (if not `NULL`). There is guaranteed at least one row per character without any `NULL`-s.

So I need to get a table where I could show current status of every character at the end.
With their last rank, last job and resulting sum of money. A table like this one.

```
table characters_status
+----+--------+---------+-------+
| id |  rank  |   job   | money |
+----+--------+---------+-------+
| 1  |   3    | tinker  |  35   |
|  2 |    2   |  no job |   14  |
| 3  |   1    | soldier |   1   |
+----+--------+---------+-------+
```

What even worse, table `characters_changes` is a temporary table.
datetime in it comes from another table of events.
So as it is temporary, I can only query it once. But there can be any number of characters and most likely going to be more columns like rank and job.

The whole system is needed to provide the possibility to get statuses for all characters at any given datetime by ignoring all changes after that. But that part is easy for me, so I left it out of scope of my question.

Comment: Since it is a temporary table, you cannot do it without creating more temporary tables, as you'll need join to a subquery aggregating the same table. _It seems to me the "snapshot" you say you already have working should be just as difficult, if not moreso._

Comment: Wait...I have an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, I think:

```
SELECT id
   , CASE WHEN INSTR(ranks, '|') = 0 THEN ranks ELSE LEFT(ranks, INSTR(ranks, '|')-1) END AS rank
   , CASE WHEN INSTR(jobs, '|') = 0 THEN jobs ELSE LEFT(jobs, INSTR(jobs, '|')-1) END AS job
   , monies
FROM
(
   SELECT id
      , GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY datetime DESC SEPARATOR '|') AS ranks
      , GROUP_CONCAT(job ORDER BY datetime DESC SEPARATOR '|') AS jobs
      , SUM(money) AS monies
   FROM characters_changes
   GROUP BY id
) AS lists
;
```

Technically, you can do it without a subquery, but I broke it down this way for clarity. The alternative would be expressions like this:

`, CASE COUNT(rank) WHEN 0 THEN NULL WHEN 1 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY datetime DESC SEPARATOR '|') ELSE LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY datetime DESC SEPARATOR '|'), INSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY datetime DESC SEPARATOR '|'), '|')-1) END AS rank`

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END AS rank
   , CASE WHEN INSTR(jobs, '|') = 0 THEN jobs ELSE LEFT(jobs, INSTR(' at line 2

alternative expression produced the same error.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out - there are missing closing parentheses for LEFT functions. And before missing parentheses there are also should be -1 added to each INSTR function inside each LEFT function. Please correct it and I will gratefully accept your answer.

Comment: Without that "-1" it returns "string|" with "|" at the end in each 'cell'. It's fine if there "LEFT(ranks, INSTR(ranks, '|')-1)" and "LEFT(jobs, INSTR(jobs, '|')-1)"

Comment: Fixed that now too. Who is helping who here? ;P

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here and didn't know if I should accept an answer which is right in concept but not exact, or should I rewrite it myself without mistakes as my own separate answer. Excuse me.

Comment: I'm not criticizing or offended, just kidding around. Typically, I've seen answers accepted with typos and oversights like I had as long as they got the person posting the question where they needed to go. Answers often don't always have the exact code/query needed anyway. Whether it is accepted before or after I make such corrections doesn't bother me, but I do personally prefer my errors, typos, etc... be pointed out so I can correct them for possible future references; you never know if the next person that comes across it might not be able to figure out the oversights.

Comment: Even if I (or someone else) don't get around to fixing them, the comment alone can be enough to make the answer "complete" for future readers.